# Bool statement in a while loop c#

Tags: c#, boolean

For this code, I had a goto start; statement to repeat the section until a valid name was entered, however my teacher does not like the goto so I had to change it.

Currently this is what i got but I'm not sure why is it not working. To begin with the program wont even start cuz later in the code I use the input userName and it does not recognize it when I use it in the bool statement. For the purpose of testing it I removed the userName line later on and the program opens but skips the bool statement.

Please help me make this work. thanks

```
bool nameValidation = true;
while (nameValidation == false) {
    Console.Write("Enter your name: ");  // Asks for your name
    userName = Console.ReadLine();

    if (Regex.IsMatch(userName, @"^[a-zA-Z- ]+$"))  // Validates the input containts characters and/or spaces
    {
        nameValidation = true;              
    }
    else  // Error message if the input is not valid
    {
        Console.Clear();  // Clear screen
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid name.");
        nameValidation = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: because at the top you set `nameValidation` to true, so it will never execute the loop. Your loop is only executed if `nameValidation` is false.

Comment: the loop will not be executed because the condition is wrong 
you initialized the bool variable as true and you want the loop to work when the variable is false so change the first line to `bool nameValidation = true;` and it will work fine

Comment: ah thanks guys that works however I still have the problem where if I use the userName string later on the program wont open I get the error of "use of unassigned local variable"

Comment: nvm fixed it thanks a lot ever1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the nameavalidation = false

```
bool nameValidation = false;
while (nameValidation == false) {
Console.Write("Enter your name: ");  // Asks for your name
userName = Console.ReadLine();

if (Regex.IsMatch(userName, @"^[a-zA-Z- ]+$"))  // Validates the input containts characters and/or spaces
 {
    nameValidation = true;              
 }
else  // Error message if the input is not valid
 {
    Console.Clear();  // Clear screen
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid name.");
    nameValidation = false;
  }
}
```